# How to customize the Soap message?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have an auto generated code that is generated from the WSDL.
I want to send an additional parameter in the Soap Body.
The request is sent such way, but i want to implement the `<position>` and `<positionvar>`, the rest of the code is implemented (i want to send even position and positionvar in the request which is not implemented.

```
<svc:getSomething>
 <module>
     ...........
     ..............
     .................
     ..................
 <position>a</position>
 <positionvar>b</positionvar>
 .............
 </module>
```

Here i want to add `<position>` and `<positionvar>`.

i am using VS 2010 C# win forms.

Comment: Your best bet is to modify the WSDL, then regenerate your code.  Otherwise, Google "C# customize soap message": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkwy2d72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @paulsm4- i want to make changes in the overridden class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking you want to modify the WSDL schema so that you could add another element inside the Soap body? You need to add the elements like so in your WSDL schema:

```
<s:element name="getSomething">         
   <s:complexType>      
     <s:sequence>
            ... 
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="position" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="positionvar" type="s:string"/>
     </s:sequence>  
   </s:complexType>     
</s:element>
```

Then re-add the WSDL for visualstudio to parse it.

The above is just an example that I derived from your SOAP body. Adjust it as necessary for your own WSDL.

Comment: @l46kok-no i want to add the new parameter to the soap body through code changes because i have an overridden partial service class. I dont want to change the WSDL. Just want to add these parameters to my Soap request.

Comment: Then as paulsm4 pointed out, you need to use the [SOAP Service methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkwy2d72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to achieve what you want. It gets messy pretty quickly, but it should get the job done.

Comment: actually i have these properties <position> and <positionvar> in my WSDL, i just want to implement them and send them in the request, is there no option to provide or send additional parameter to Soap body/message just like we can add our own custom headers?

Comment: @roopinin Alright I'm a little bit confused, you say that you have the properties that you want to send defined in the WSDL yet you are asking how to send them in the request? Maybe I misunderstood you gravely, show us some code on how you are actually handling the requests.

Comment: @l46kok- at present there is no position and positionvar sent in the request. only the other values in that which i have mentioned in dots are sent, now i have to even send this position and positionvar in the body, but my properties has this in the generated auto code which doesnt have the implementation of this and it is also not sent in request. [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string position{get{return this.positionField;}set
{this.positionField = value;}}

Comment: @roopinin Have you actually populated the properties `position` and `positionvar` with some value before sending the request? The elements aren't included in the message body unless if they are filled with a value.

Comment: @l46kok- yes, these parameters doesn't appear in the request at all now. i can see the rest. It is implemented in the service part, but through my application, i am not able to send or see this in the log, in the request body. I want to implement these two extra parameters.